# How can I reset a Windows 10 user profile bound to a domain user?

Tags: windows-10, exchange, office365, user-profiles, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way that I can reset the Windows profile of my domain user so that all my files stay there and I only need to reconfigure my user environment?

My Outlook client stopped connecting to Office 365 Exchange and after several dead ends (re-add Exchange account, new Outlook profile, Office self-heal, Office re-installation, etc.) I've found that everything seems to work Ok from a new Windows profile in the same machine. I'm guessing that removing and recreating my profile would do the trick, but better yet would be to avoid having to move files to a new directory.

Comment: Try to remove the computer from the domain and join again.

Comment: I'm afraid if I do that I won't be able to rejoin the domain as I am a local administrator, not a domain administrator.

Comment: In that case I can't think of any other option than starting a new profile. Finding out what went wrong with a profile is mission impossible.

Comment: I'm thinking I'm followin that route. I've found this post in SpiceWorks that seems a good way of starting a new profile keeping my current user folder name. It's just that I can't find a `ProfileGuid` key in my registry. Does that key still exist in Windows 10?

Comment: `ProfileGuid` is found under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\IDConfigDB\Hardware Profiles`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult and up to impossible to fix corruption in a user profile,
since there are too many possibilities.

For a computer in a domain, I would advise trying to remove the computer from the
domain and rejoin, although I understand that this is impossible in your case.

Therefore your only solution is to start a new user profile.

There are many tutorials on the Internet, which basically amount to copying
files or to setting in the registry for the new account some pointers to your
main folders such as Documents.

You could also use a straight move of the important folders under the `C:\Users`
folder, such as Documents and Desktop.
If you have a Microsoft account moving will be even easier.

Answer (score 0):

You might be over thinking it. If it was a "Corrupted Profile", you would experience more issues. From what you said, it's just related to email. You said you created a new outlook profile but not the PST. I would recommend C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook and delete the pst file in there so outlook re-creates it. Also verify the user's password didn't expire.

Answer (score 0):

Before following these steps make sure to save your files in another location than C:\Users<Affected account>. Maybe in a new folder C:\Temp or USB or second HDD/SSD drive or Network drive.

Also another idea before trying this.
Create a new Outlook Mail Profile

- Open Control Panel (All Control Panel Items / Large or small icons view)
- Open Mail (Microsoft Outlook)
- Select Show Profiles...
- Click on Add
- Name it whatever you like
- Setup the mail account
- Under "Always use this profile" set the new Mail Profile you just made
- Click Ok
- Open Outlook and have a look

New User Profile:

- Login from another account with Admin rights
- Open the "Advanced System Settings"

  - Either via Settings > System > About > Advanced system settings or via Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
- Go to Advanced > User Profiles > Settings...
- Remove your Profile stored by selecting it and clicking on delete
- Login with the affected account and do the settings needed.

Good luck have fun. ;)